# Javascript date time not same with different locale

Tags: javascript, datetime, locale

We send time to javascript as long type from server. Javascript date function converts it to date based on users locale. We do not want that. We would like it to be set as date as it comes from the server.

For example; we send `2013-06-05 17:00:00` from server, on client side it is shown as `2013-06-05 15:00:00` on users browsers. I want to show what comes from server. How can I correct this problem?

Comment: well if you use client code, it's perfectly normal it's using client locale. If you wish to get the value from your server, just display it using server language...

Comment: Will you show the code that does the conversion?

Comment: welcome to JS date hell.  The only way to have the client show the server time is for the server to tell the client what its own UTC offset is.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is common with JavaScript.

There are two ways you might handle this:

**Option 1**

Send UTC time from your server.  You can send it as an integer, or as an ISO8601 string with a `Z` offset.  In JavaScript, always *display* that value in UTC time.

**Option 2**

Send date/time string in ISO8601 format from the server.  Send it with an unspecified zone offset (*without* a `Z` value or an offset such as `-04:00`).  Parse that value on the client, either with a modern browser that supports ISO8601 format, or with a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.org).

Since you did not provide any code examples in your question, I'm not going to provide any code in my answer, or elaborate further.  If you would like to update your question to show exactly what you are doing, what you have tried, and what didn't work, then I will be happy to remove this paragraph and show you code that can implement either of these options.  You will find that you get much better results on StackOverflow if you do some research and explain your findings in code.